# How can I add dynamic layout in Angular View component?

Tags: angular, angular8

How can I managed to implement dynamic views in `Angular 8`? Given an `Ajax` call with dynamic `HTML` view such as:

```
<div class='col1'>
 <my-component1></my-component1>
 <my-component2></my-component2>
</div>
```

It is obvious that the HTML will change, such as adding more rows or columns with differents components. I try to implement a kind of dashboard. It's possible to render this dynamic layout? I Think that  `ComponentFactoryResolver` does not add html inside component.

Answer (score 0):

**Try the below , if you want to bind different HTML content for the same component**

Create the reusable component with  tag. By this content projection technique everything you put inside this component will be loaded inside the  tag

for ex: create `<custom-button>` component and add a `<ng-content></ng-content>` inside its template.

So when you add `<custom-button>First</custom-button>`Will show "First" as the content and second will show second as the content.

If you want to bind html content then

```
<custom-button>
<div [innerHtml]="first"> </div>
</custom-button>
```

Here first will be the variable that needs to be defined in ts file

public first ="First component";

[CheckThisSample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-content-lddy6i)

Comment: I try this <app-dynamic [innerHTML]="dynamicContent"></app-dynamic>, but doesn't print angular components... I think that I do something like this.

public dynamicContent = '<div class='row'>
<ng-template ngbTabContent [smaDynamicHost]="component1"></template> 
<ng-template ngbTabContent [smaDynamicHost]="component2"></template> 
</div>';

<app-dynamic [innerHTML]="dynamicContent"></app-dynamic>